# Magento 2 Point Of Sale - POS options?

Tags: magento, magento2, point-of-sale

I'm currently running a Magento Store in Version 2.2.3

I am need of a POS extension that can operate online and offline for when i take physical offline sales in a shop or at an external event.

After trying 3-4 POS extensions already, I have just installed Webkul POS for a few different reasons.  It's a one time payment which is very important. It's got a very easy to understand interface and it syncs sales to keep my stock correct when it's connected to my Wifi, but it can also work offsite and store offline orders to be synced when it reconnects to wifi.

However, despite being cheap and easy to use, it's also horribly riddled with bugs and shortcomings. As below:

- Offline sales don't sync when the system goes back online
- Doesn't work on Safari
- Can't show Configurable products
- No way for it to process disabled products through the checkout
- Crashes fairly regularly
- No way to delete unsynced orders (which happens to be all
  offline orders)
- some other technical bugs which i have reported to their support system.

So without spending crazy money, is there actually any POS extensions which people have found to work well?

Answer (score 1):

So one year on with Webkul POS and I thought I would post an update.

Webkul support worked on and fixed approximately 25 - 30 bugs in the software and despite being a little slow it worked for the most part.  Their support team was very helpful in fixed multiple issues.
Whilst planning an upgrade on Magento 2 I asked the webkul support team if their latest version included the multitude of fixes which were completed on my build and if it was compatible with the latest verion of magento and php.  Without hesitation, i was told, yes everything will work and they arranged a download of the latest version which we got and installed into our newly upgraded magento 2.3.3

Back to square 1.
All bugs returned and extension was unusable.  It simply didn't work.  After support refused to look at the issues I paid for extended support and they started to fix bugs.  After some bug fixes and getting our heads around the magento Multi Source Inventory, we have got the pos to work or at least function enough to use it.

So here's my current issue.  Webkul POS requires it's own source for stock (not sure why it can't use the default one) so now I have my default source which the website uses, and another source or stock qty table that the POS software uses and the 2 stock numbers are completely independent and do not sync. 
 This means if I sell an item in my shop using POS, my website stock does not update and it is still possible for people online to buy an item that I may be sold out of.  This is until I manually adjust the stock.

Therefore in my eyes, the POS extension is totally pointless.
Does anyone else have the latest magento and had the same issue with any other POS systems?  I think the MSI in the new magento seems to be causing some similar stock control problems.  I can't really justify a monthly payment style POS extension because this experience has made me question if any of them work properly in the latest version of M2.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late to this post, but I know exactly what you mean about Webkul POS. Disappointing and just confusing to use tbh.

Sad truth is if you're not willing to pay for the good stuff, you'll get what you pay for. One-time payment for Webkul is all well and good, but it's got the usability and functions corresponding to that. If you want to experience the really good stuff, you've got to pay for it.

I know people who have had success with Connect POS - https://www.connectpos.com/magento-pos/ - and there's no extra hidden fees that surprise you down the line. A pretty powerful extension in my view cos it's got AI and PWA capabilities. The best option for Magento 2 imho.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone got any experience with Lightspeed POS?  It's currently looking like a front runner to become a webkul replacement for us.  I can't really fine too many reviews or any information from any users.  We're moving to a new store soon and need something a little bit slicker at a reasonable cost.